# Converting a set of tuples into sets

Tags: python, set

I am trying to convert the following set of tuples into a group of sets to find the intersection using Python 3

```
{(1, 3, 5), (3, 4, 5), (6, 3, 5)}
```

I have essentially taken a delimited string and converted to these integer based tuples within a set, but I want to see the intersection of the integers within each tuple.

The problem is I don't know how big my string is going to be, and how many items are in each delimited string, so I thought converting to a tuple of integers was the cleanest to work with. Now I'm stuck on where to go from here as I can't create a set of sets, and so I'd have to dynamically create sets to use the intersection function, is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Do you need the `set` functionality of the parent container at all times? If not, you could temporarily have a `tuple` of `set`, and then get back to `set` to `tuple` afterwards if needed.

Comment: `set.intersection([set(tup) for tup in my_set])`